# Is it possible to return empty in react render function?

Tags: reactjs

I have a notification component, and I have a timeout setting for it. After timeout I call `this.setState({isTimeout:true})`.

What I want to do is if already timeout, I want just render nothing:

```
render() {
  let finalClasses = "" + (this.state.classes || "");
  if (isTimeout){
    return (); // here has some syntax error
  }
  return (<div>{this.props.children}</div>);
}
```

The problem is:

> return (); // here has some syntax error

Answer (score 437, accepted):

Yes you can, but instead of blank, simply return `null` if you don't want to `render` anything from component, like this:

```
return (null);
```

---

Another important point is, inside JSX if you are rendering element conditionally, then in case of `condition=false`, you can return any of these values `false, null, undefined, true`. As per **[DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored)**:

> `booleans (true/false), null, and undefined` are **valid children**,
>   they will be Ignored means they simply don’t render.

All these `JSX` expressions will render to the same thing:

```
<div />

<div></div>

<div>{false}</div>

<div>{null}</div>

<div>{undefined}</div>

<div>{true}</div>
```

**Example:**

Only odd values will get rendered, because for even values we are returning `null`.

```js
const App = ({ number }) => {
  if(number%2) {
    return (
      <div>
        Number: {number}
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  return (null);           //===> notice here, returning null for even values
}

const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    {data.map(el => <App key={el} number={el} />)}
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: Why are you returning (null) and not simply null?

Comment: @wederer there is no difference between `return null` and `return (null)` they are same :)

Comment: But the way, you can't just drop out of your function (which is the same as returning undefined). If you don't have any `return` then React gives an error.  So the `return null` is required.

Comment: Btw, returning empty array from component or JSX expression still counts by react as valid empty value. This is in particular useful to understand while making `data.map(...)` in JSX when `data` is variable which could have no elements in it.

Comment: @MayankShukla `return null` and `return (null)` are not the same; a dimension of the result may be the same but the latter includes 2 useless characters

Comment: @GeoffreyHale That clarifies :)

Comment: The new react docs cover this as well:
https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering#conditionally-returning-nothing-with-null

Answer (score 55):

Some answers are slightly incorrect and point to the wrong part of the docs:

If you want a component to render nothing, just return `null`, as per [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#preventing-component-from-rendering):

> In rare cases you might want a component to hide itself even though it
> was rendered by another component. To do this return null instead of
> its render output.

If you try to return `undefined` for example, you'll get the following error:

> Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return
> statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

As pointed out by other answers, `null`, `true`, `false` and `undefined` are valid children which is useful for conditional rendering **inside** your jsx, but it you want your component to hide / render nothing, just return `null`.

**EDIT React 18:**

React 18 will allow rendering `undefined` instead of throwing. See this [announcement](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/75).

Answer (score 24):

Yes you can return an empty value from a React render method.

You can return any of the following: `false, null, undefined, or true`

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored):

> `false`, `null`, `undefined`, and `true` are valid children. They
> simply don’t render.

You could write

```
return null; or
return false; or
return true; or
return <div>{undefined}</div>;
```

However `return null` is the most preferred as it signifies that nothing is returned

Comment: return undefined is wrong. it would return error. Instead return <div>{undefined}</div> is right way.

Comment: @jaydhawan return null is the recommended way. And yes, return undefined will give error so this answer is flawed.

Comment: @jaydhawan the problem with this approch is that it will create "real" div element.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Typescript and your component/function has return type `React.Element`, you will get the following error.

> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string |
> JSXElementConstructor>'.

The solution is `React.Fragment`.

```
return <React.Fragment />
```

or

```
return <></>
```

Comment: According to this eslint rule, empty fragments are not advisable https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-useless-fragment.md

Comment: Null is more performant too. With null there's nothing for react to process, it just moves on. A fragment has to be processed, even if it isn't very much.

Answer (score 7):

Slightly off-topic but if you ever needed a class-based component that never renders anything and you are happy to use some yet-to-be-standardised ES syntax, you might want to go:

```
render = () => null
```

This is basically an arrow method that currently requires the [transform-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties) Babel plugin. React will not let you define a component without the `render` function and this is the most concise form satisfying this requirement that I can think of.

I'm currently using this trick in a variant of [ScrollToTop](https://gist.github.com/chris-kobrzak/708f31976be5fac2aa265816d6a03f2a) borrowed from the `react-router` documentation. In my case, there's only a single instance of the component and it doesn't render anything, so a short form of "render null" fits nice in there.

Comment: The code has been already finished, but I like this style, looks the simplest code.

Answer (score 4):

for those developers who came to this question about checking where they can return null from component instead of checking in ternary mode to render or not render the component, the answer is YES, You Can!

i mean instead of this junk ternary condition inside your jsx in render part of your component:

```
// some component body
return(
  <section>
   {/* some ui */}
   
   { someCondition && <MyComponent /> }
   or
   { someCondition ? <MyComponent /> : null }

   {/* more ui */}
  </section>
)
```

you can check than condition inside your component like:

```
const MyComponent:React.FC = () => {
  
  // get someCondition from context at here before any thing


  if(someCondition) return null; // i mean this part , checking inside component! 
  
  return (
    <section>   
     // some ui...
    </section>
  )
}
```

Just Consider that in my case i provide the `someCondition` variable from a context in upper level component ( for example, just consider in your mind ) and i don't need to prop drill the `someCondition` inside `MyComponent`.

Just look how clean view your code gets after that, i mean you don't need to user ternary operator inside your JSX, and your parent component would like below:

```
// some component body
return(
  <section>
   {/* some ui */}
   
   <MyComponent />

   {/* more ui */}
  </section>
)
```

and `MyComponent` would handle the rest for you!

Answer (score 1):

We can return like this,

```
return <React.Fragment />;
```

Comment: is this better or worse than returning `null`?

Comment: @bitstrider using Fragment instead of null triggers just a lose of memory.

Comment: not sure why this answer is downvoted, its shows the developer's intent explicitly

Comment: @ktingle From react docs: "A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM."

null is more correct, "React docs, In rare cases you might want a component to hide itself even though it was rendered by another component. To do this return null instead of its render output."

Answer (score 0):

Returning falsy value in the render() function will render nothing. So you can just do

```
 render() {
    let finalClasses = "" + (this.state.classes || "");
    return !isTimeout && <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
```

Comment: if you return 0 (a falsy value), it'll render