# let useEffect watch a condition and have it trigger only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

React's `useEffect` looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  effect
  return () => {
    cleanup
  }
}, [input])
```

where `input` is a list of values that trigger the effect when changed.

Let's say that I'm watching a number and I only want to trigger the effect when the number reaches 10. Is it possible to do that?

So far the best I could come up with is to encode the watched expression in a boolean value. The effect is then triggered twice, once when the boolean flips from false to true and a second time when it flips back to false. This is once too many.
Here's a small example:

```
export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const hit10 = num === 10;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("resetting");
    setNum(0);
  }, [hit10]);

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        setNum(num + 1);
      }}
    >
      {num}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: The useEffect wil run when hit10 change, you need pass a check in useEffect like hit10 && setNum(0).

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620799/react-hook-useeffect-is-called-conditionally

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use another variable like `hit10`, 
You can just put a condition inside `useEffect()` hook to check the number's value every time that the component was rendered.

```
 import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

    export default function App() {
      const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

      useEffect(() => {
        if(num === 10) {
          console.log("resetting");
          setNum(0);
        }
      }, [num]);

      return (
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setNum(num + 1);
          }}
        >
          {num}
        </button>
      );
    }
```