# React Router Redirect if location.state is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
    
    function Update(data) {
       if(!data.location.state) return <Redirect to="/"/>
       const [name, setName] = useState(data.location.state.name);
       return (<>Hello World</>)
}
```

Error :  React Hook "useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620799/react-hook-useeffect-is-called-conditionally)

Answer (score 2):

(Similar [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57620799/7974948) that might include helpful answers.)

[From the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level):

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, **always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns**.

So *the `useState` hook call should be moved to the top of the component*.

You could do:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
    
function Update(data) { 
  const [name, setName] = useState(
    data.location.state ? data.location.state.name : ''
  );

  if(!data.location.state) return <Redirect to="/"/>

  return (
    <>Hello World</>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `useState` to the top of the function (above the if condition) or move the if condition inside `useEffect` and redirect from there.

```js
function Update(data) {
 const [name, setName] = useState(data.location.state.name);
     
 if(!data.location.state) {
      return <Redirect to="/"/>
 }

  return (<>Hello World</>)
}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong.  useState(data.location.state.name) will throw error cz it will be undefined. That is why I'm checking at the top & was trying to redirect.

Comment: You can avoid the error using `data?.location?.state?.name ?? ""`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
    
function Update(data) { 
  const [name, setName] = useState(
    data.location.state ? data.location.state.name : ''
  );

  if(!data.location.state) return <Navigate replace to="/"/>

  return (
    <>Hello World</>
  );
}
```