# How can I call React hooks conditionally, to fix linting error

Tags: react-hooks, eslint

How can I correctly refactor the code below to call hooks conditionally?

I currently get the linting error:

> React Hook "useCallback" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.

```
const BreakdownProductsWidget = ({ b2b2c }) => {


  if (!coverProduct && !IsPayg && !b2b2c) {
    return null;
  }
  if (!coverProduct && IsPayg) {
    return (
      <RestrictedCustomersWidget
        ...
      />
    );
  }

  const filterCakeItemsToDisplay = (arrayOfItems) =>
    arrayOfItems.filter(
      (item) =>
        item.isActive &&
        (item?.productType === BreakdownProductEnum.COVER_OPTIONS ||
          item?.productType === BreakdownProductEnum.COVER_PACKAGE),
    );

  const renderCakeHeader = (items) =>
    items?.map((product, index) => (
      <CheckListWidget
    ...
      />
    ));

  const renderCakeOptions = (items) =>
    items?.map((product) =>
      product?.Benefits?.map((benefitName, index) => (
        <CheckListWidget
          ...
        />
      )),
    );


  const getCakeTypeOptions = useCallback(() => {
    if (IsPackage && CoverType && Products) {
      const items = filterCakeItemsToDisplay(Products);
      return (
        <>
          {renderCakeHeader(items)}
          {renderCakeOptions(items)}
        </>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }, [Products]);

 // linting error, React Hook "useCallback" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.
  const getB2B2COptions = useCallback(() => {
    if (b2b2c) {
      return Products?.map((product, index) => (
        <CheckListWidget
          ...
        />
      ));
    }
    return null;
  }, [Products]);

  const Wrapper = b2b2c ? View : TouchableOpacity;

  const b2b2cHasOnlyLegalProducts =
    b2b2c && Products?.every((x) => x.isLegalInsuranceProduct);

  return (
    <View
      style={panel.container}
      {...AccessibilityHelper('Breakdown widget container')}>
      <Wrapper onPress={() => navigate(AppRoutes.Offers.Name)}>
        <View style={panel.titleWrapper}>
          <Text
            style={panel.title}
            {...AccessibilityHelper('Breakdown widget cover type')}>
            {b2b2cHasOnlyLegalProducts
              ? 'Your cover'
              : coverProduct?.productName}
          </Text>
        </View>
        {b2b2cHasOnlyLegalProducts ? null : (
          <>
            <Text
              ...>
              {coverProduct?.text?.covered?.short}
            </Text>
          </>
        )}
        {getCakeTypeOptions()}
        {getB2B2COptions()}
        {coverOptions &&
          coverOptions
            .filter((p) => p.isActive)
            .map((product, index) => (
              <CheckListWidget
               ...
              />
            ))}

        {b2b2c ? null : (
          <>
            <Text
             ...>
              {breakdownProducts.breakdownExtras}
            </Text>
            {activeBreakdown &&
            Array.isArray(activeBreakdown) &&
            activeBreakdown.length > 0 ? (
              activeBreakdown.map((product, index) => (
                <CheckListWidget
                ...
                />
              ))
            ) : (
              <Text style={boxWidget.subTitle}>
                {breakdownProducts.noBreakdownExtras}
              </Text>
            )}

            <CallToActionWidget
              linkTitle={membershipOverview.breakdownCoverCallToAction}
            />
          </>
        )}
      </Wrapper>
      {state.showModal && (
        <MessageModals
        ...
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default BreakdownProductsWidget;

BreakdownProductsWidget.propTypes = {
  b2b2c: PropTypes.bool,
};
BreakdownProductsWidget.defaultProps = {
  b2b2c: false,
};
```

Comment: It's hard to see from your snippet, but do you have a `return` before the hook? React requires all hooks to be called before returning and hooks cannot be in `if` statements

Comment: Added more code to snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move hooks like `useCallback` above any early return, since all hooks in a component must all be each time the component function is run. In your case:

```
const BreakdownProductsWidget = ({ b2b2c }) => {

  // <- useCallback goes here

  if (!coverProduct && !IsPayg && !b2b2c) {
    return null;
  }
```

For more information see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57620799/react-hook-useeffect-is-called-conditionally?rq=2).