# ReactJS unexpected token in return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return nothing if a context variable is set to none.

But I get unexpected token on if?

```
return (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
        {context => (
            if(context.objects[0] !== "none")
                return;
            <ul>
              {context.objects.map((object, key) => {
                  return <li key={key}>{object.type}
//--- snip ----
```

Edit: The whole (working) component code is like this

```
const ObjectList = (props) => {

    return (
        <AppContext.Consumer>
            {context => (
                <ul>
                  {context.objects.map((object, key) => {
                      return <li key={key}>{object.type}&nbsp;
                            <Button
                                key={key}
                                style={{backgroundColor: "red"}}
                                onClick={() => context.deleteObject(key)}
                            >
                                x
                            </Button>
                        </li>
                   })}
                </ul>
            )}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
}
```

But this always renders 1 li element because objects has "none" as an element when it gets initialized in the context provider:

```
const [objects, setObjects] = useState(['none']);
```

I want the list only be drawn, when there is something else than "none" in the objects array.

Comment: Wrap your logic with braces `{` `}` after `=>` token.

Comment: Can you include info about `AppContext.Consumer`? Providing a Function as a child to that component doesn't seem like it will do anything, and that's why you're getting a lint warning about "no-unused-expressions".

Comment: What info do you need? It was working well without the context.objects[0] !== "none". The issue is just that then I get an ul with one li item that contains a "none". I want to draw the ul only when there's actual object data (anything not "none") on the context. "none" is what the objects array gets initialized with on the context provider state.

Comment: Additionally I just don't understand the logic behind this js construct here. If I create a function ({context => (.... ), why can't it have an if statement?

Comment: Hey i updated my ans. Tell me if its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use `return null` instead of just `return`.

Refer to this question for more information: [Is it possible to return empty in react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083181/is-it-possible-to-return-empty-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 1):

Use curly brackets for the body of an arrow function:

```js
        {context => {
```

When parentheses are used then inside the parentheses must be a statement, and the return value of that statement becomes the return value of the function.

Comment: This gives  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions when canged to <AppContext.Consumer> {context => { if(context.object ...

Answer (score 1):

You need `{}`

```
return (
    <AppContext.Consumer>
        {context => ({  // <- this
            if(context.objects[0] !== "none")
                return;
            return ( // <-and this 
            <ul>
              {context.objects.map((object, key) => {
                  return <li key={key}>{object.type}
//--- snip ----
```

As **()** is shorthand if u want to only return the content inside it. No logic. But if you will add `if` then it will return it and JXS will say unexpected token.

The best approach would be

```
{context &&  context.objects[0] !== "none" && (<ul>
  {context.objects.map((object, key) => (<li key={key} {object.type}>{object.data}</li></ul>)})}
```

---

You can visit [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-breeze-23znw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to have see it working.

---

[image]

Comment: this gives  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," on the dot in if(context.objects

Comment: That is still not working. Now all context in the scope are undefined:   Line 9:14:   'context' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 9:25:   'context' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 11:20:  'context' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 16:48:  'context' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I think u did not define *context* You can either look at it or upload the full code.

Comment: It is defined when I have the line start like {context => (<ul>
                  {context.objects.map... but it's undefined in your version

Comment: Sorry, codesandbox never worked quite well for me, I only see a white browser tab in there. Anyhow, are you sure to use context[0].objects and not context.objects[0]? You define context as a variable although my context is a react context.

Comment: @Supertyp it depend. I i declared it as *[{ a: "a", object: [{ b: "adsda" }] }]*. I am updating my ans with screenshot so u can see it

Comment: Yeah I don't even see the "Hello CodeSandbox" (latest firefox). But that's not the first codesandbox example where this happened, I see it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

You should return null if you don't want to render anything from the component. Like this

```
return (null);
```