# I am passing in props but i cant see them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

So I am passing in some data that i have saved in a state. I am then trying to pass that information as props on to another component. However, when I console.log it shows as undefined.

Here is the page i am passing information from:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import IpContext from '../../IpContext'
import { useContext } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import PostIssues from '../Trainee/PostIssues/PostIssues';

const LoginPage = props => {
const [userDetails, setuserDetails] = useState([]);
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
const [memberType, setMemberType] = useState("");


    const getLogin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (memberType === "trainee") {
            axios.get("http://" + ip + "/trainee/findByUsername/" + username)
                .then(response => {
                    setuserDetails(response.data);
                    console.log(userDetails)
                    console.log(response.data.id);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                });
        } else {
            console.log("ignore")
        }
    }

    const validate = (e) => {
        if (userDetails.username === username && userDetails.password === password) {
            props.history.push("/postIssue");
            // userDetails[0].map((issue) => (
            <PostIssues
                // number={number}
                userDetails={userDetails}
            />
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            ReactDOM.render(<p style={{ color: "red" }}>Username/Password wrong</p>, document.getElementById('failed-message'));

        }
    }
return (
        <>

            <div className="loginDiv">
                <h1 className="loginHeading">Login</h1>
                <div>
                    <form className="ml-3" id="loginForm" onSubmit={validate}>
                        <input name="username" className="loginInput" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)} required></input> <br></br>
                        <input name="password" className="loginInput" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} required></input> <br></br>
                        <select defaultValue="" name="traineeTrainer" onInput={e => setMemberType(e.target.value)} onChange={getLogin} >
                            <option value="" disabled hidden >Position</option>
                            <option value="trainer">Trainer</option>
                            <option value="trainee">Trainee</option>
                        </select>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" id="loginButton" type="submit">Login</button>
                        <div>
                            <Link to="/createAccount">
                                <button style={{ backgroundColor: "darkred" }} className="btn btn-primary" id="signUpButton" type="button">Create an account</button>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            {/* Login failed will appear here */}
            <div id="failed-message"></div>
        </>
    )
}

export default LoginPage
```

And this is where i want to receive information:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Issue from '../../Trainer/Issue';
import IpContext from '../../../IpContext'
import { useContext } from 'react';

const PostIssues = props => {

    console.log(props.userDetails.username);

return(
)
}

export default PostIssues;
```

When I run this on the browser I get and error which says

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined".

Why is it undefined if i am passing it as props?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not returning anything from the `LoginPage` component, so it won't render anything.

Comment: I am calling a return statement, I have updated it now. Please check. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Also, you're initializing the state with an array `useState([])` then using it like it's a single object `userDetails.username`.

Comment: And you're manipulating the DOM manually with `ReactDOM.render` in callbacks, which is an anti-pattern in React. It used to work like this with jQuery, but React is data driven. Update some state with the error and render once in the render cycle.

Comment: you're not calling the validate function anywhere, you should check the function returns a React Node and be sure to call that function, in order to achieve what @RinkeshGolwala suggests

Answer (score -1):

You're not actually returning anything, even though you have a `return()` in there. Try `return(null)` and read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42083181/is-it-possible-to-return-empty-in-react-render-function) to see why.

Additionally, I would recommend you try to debug this by using the developer tools in your browser. The [React tools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html) are quite handy and they allow you to inspect props and state.

Try rendering `props.userDetails.username` in a `<div>` inside your return statement to see the page render the component.